# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I use this library for showing a parsed epub file, which supports showing .css.
[flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview).

```
        var doc = state.book.Chapters.last.HtmlContent.split('<head>');
        var styledTML = "\n" +
            doc.first +
            "\n" +
            "<head>" +
            "<style>" +
            state.book.Content.Css['styles.css'].Content +
            "</style>" +
            doc.last;

        return Material(
          child: InAppWebView(
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              controller.loadData(data: styledTML);
            },
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(),
          ),
        );
      }
```

This code works perfectly on iOS, but on Android I have error:

```
E/flutter ( 7880): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview
E/flutter ( 7880):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:91)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:96)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:60)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/flutter ( 7880):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/flutter ( 7880): , null)
E/flutter ( 7880): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter ( 7880): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
E/flutter ( 7880): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7880): #2      AndroidViewController._create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:640:54)
E/flutter ( 7880): #3      AndroidViewController.setSize (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:557:14)
E/flutter ( 7880): #4      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:174:29)
E/flutter ( 7880): #5      RenderAndroidView.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:155:5)
E/flutter ( 7880): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1703:9)
E/flutter ( 7880): #7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 7880): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 7880): #9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 7880): #10     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1584:7)
E/flutter ( 7880): #11     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
E/flutter ( 7880): #12     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:344:19)
E/flutter ( 7880): #13     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:774:13)
E/flutter ( 7880): #14     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
E/flutter ( 7880): #15     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
E/flutter ( 7880): #16     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
E/flutter ( 7880): #17     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
E/flutter ( 7880): #18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter ( 7880): #19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter ( 7880): #20     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter ( 7880): #21     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
E/flutter ( 7880): #22     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
E/flutter ( 7880):
```

I tried `flutter clean`. Restarting IDE. My project is AndroidX project and I put Internet permission in Manifest, my project is more than API 21, but it still crashes. How can I reflect this HTML. I appreciate your time and ideas. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)! Now you can use version `3.0.0`+. The latest version is `3.3.0`.

Comment: I've got 3.3.0 and it still displays this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter clean
```

run the app afterwards